# Telethon posts grabber does't work with links

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon, content-grabber

I used the code to create a user-bot that sends messages from one telegram channel to my telegram channel. The user-boot as a whole works well, but there are 2 problems.

1. In the channel where I get posts, there is a text formatted as a link. In posts on my channel, the link in the text disappears, this usual text.
2. Posts with ordinary links do not go to my channel at all.
   How to fix it?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon import errors
import asyncio
import re
# ----
api_id = 
api_hash = ""
# ----
channels = '@'  # channel from
my_channel = '@'  # channel to

KEYS = {} # Replacing words
# ----
Bad_Keys = [] # If there is a bad key in the post, the post is not published
# ----
tags = ''# Adding text
# ----
with TelegramClient('myApp13', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    print("～Activated～")

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
    async def Messages(event):
        if not [element for element in Bad_Keys
                if event.raw_text.lower().__contains__(element)]:
            text = event.raw_text
            for i in KEYS:
                text = re.sub(i, KEYS[i], text)
            if not event.grouped_id\
                    and not event.message.forward:
                try:
                    await client.send_message(
                        entity=my_channel,
                        file=event.message.media,
                        message=text + tags,
                        parse_mode='md',
                        link_preview=False)
                except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
                    print(f'[!] Flud errror. Wait: {e.seconds} seconds')
                    await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('[!] Error', e)
            elif event.message.text and not event.message.media\
                and not event.message.forward\
                    and not event.grouped_id:
                try:
                    await client.send_message(
                        entity=my_channel,
                        message=text + tags,
                        parse_mode='md',
                        link_preview=False)
                except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
                    print(f'[!] Flud error. Wait: {e.seconds} seconds')
                    await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('[!] Error', e)
            elif event.message.forward:
                try:
                    await event.message.forward_to(my_channel)
                except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
                    print(f'[!] Flud error. Wait: {e.seconds} seconds')
                except Exception as e:
                    print('[!] Error', e)

    @client.on(events.Album(chats=channels))
    async def Album(event):
        text = event.original_update.message.message
        print(text)
        if not [element for element in Bad_Keys
                if text.lower().__contains__(element)]:
            for i in KEYS:
                text = re.sub(i, KEYS[i], text)
            try:
                await client.send_message(
                    entity=my_channel,
                    file=event.messages,
                    message=text + tags,
                    parse_mode='md',
                    link_preview=False)
            except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
                print(f'[!] Flud error. Wait: {e.seconds} seconds')
                await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds)
            except Exception as e:
                print('[!] Error', e)

    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you forwarding the message or just the part of it? have you tried client.forward_messages() instead?

I suggest you try to remove link_preview=False from your send_message request

Comment: Hi @dotheM! I removed 'link_preview=False', but nothing changed. Then I replaced 'send_message' with 'forward_messages', posted text with link in first channel and got this text in console: " [!] Error forward_messages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file' "

Comment: So forward_message work on the text but not file, is that so? is it possible to just use forward_message for the text and send_message for files and media?